# Digital type the string " trim " and " replaceAll " can't remove the last spaces

Tags: java, trim, replaceall

I want to remove all spaces in a string of numeric types, I used the function such as `trim()`, `replaceall(" ", "")`, but the last space always goes to off.

code:

```
String str = " 13554912187 ";
//String str2 = str.replaceAll(" ", "");
String str2 = str.trim();
System.out.println(str);
System.out.println(str.length());
System.out.println(str2);
System.out.println(str2.length());
```

I want to know why.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the trailing space is actually considered whitespace by `String.trim()` - only characters with code less than or equal to `\u0020` are considered whitespace - see [`String.trim()` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--).

Some possible ways to check this:

- Copy the leading space and replace the trailing space with it (assuming the leading space works OK)
- Open the file this input comes from in a hex editor
- Debug the Java application and see what value is stored in the `String` instance for that last space

Comment: It seems that the OP has tried my example and his problem remains. It make no sense that the leading blanks are remove but the trailing aren't. They should be the same character, shouldn't they?

Comment: Solved. It was an espurious character copied from an Excel file.

Answer (score 1):

```
 String str = " 13554912187 ";
```

Trim leading and trailing blanks

```
    str.trim(); -> "13554912187"
```

For left trim:

```
    str.replaceAll("^\\s+", ""); -> "13554912187 "
```

For right trim:

```
    str.replaceAll("\\s+$", ""); -> " 13554912187"
```

Visual proof for the incredulous

[image: Visual proof]

Comment: str.trim() can't get "13554912187"，
and  str.replaceAll("\\s+$", ""); -> " 13554912187" also does't work.

Comment: @xiaopohai85707 Yes, they work. See my update above. I don't know how you're testing.

Comment: You may want to consider the answer contributed by Jiri Tousek. No need to down vote mine.

Comment: for a long time, don't know how to upload pictures, after the run, and finally a space is always going off.

Comment: <img src="http://pan.baidu.com/s/1hrbuYos" width="100" height="100">,
this is my result.

Comment: @xiaopohai85707 Are you using Eclipse IDE? Try changing your file character encoding. I insist, Jiri Tousek may have stated the cause of your problem.

Comment: @xiaopohai85707 I access the URL but can not get any image. Are you using a different character for leading and trailing blanks, one for leading blanks and another for trailing?

Comment: Thanks very much, Why I find the last. the " 13554912187 " is my excel data, I copied over directly, the last space is not a space, it is a invisible characters. because I  less than 15 reputation, so can't vote.

Answer (score -1):

String str2 = str.trim();

trim()  method remove space before and after the word.

like

```
String s=" 45654 65 ";
System.out.println(s.startsWith(" "));
System.out.println(s.endsWith(" "));

s=s.trim();
System.out.println(s.startsWith(" "));
System.out.println(s.endsWith(" "));
```

output:

```
true
true
false
false
```